# optional parameters in bison

Tags: parsing, bison

I'm toying with a BASIC interpreter in flex/bison based on [gnbasic](https://excamera.com/articles/12/gnbasic.html). I found a minor problem in the .y, bison complained about this code:

```
NEXT variable | NEXT {
    statement_t *new = mkstatement(NEXT);
    if (strlen($2) > 0) {
        new->parms.next = $2;
    }
  $$ = new;
}
```

It errored `integer out of range: ‘$2’`. I was quickly able to determine that it's because the second of the two forms, `NEXT` with no variable, doesn't have a `$2`. So that's easy, just separate this one out:

```
NEXT {
  statement_t *new = mkstatement(NEXT);
  $$ = new;
}
```

But is that the **right** solution? Is there some way I can leave these two combined and handle the optional parameter? I suspect this is not uncommon in most languages and that I'm missing the right terminology to ask Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original code is equivalent to:

```
  NEXT variable { $$ = $1; }
| NEXT {
      statement_t *new = mkstatement(NEXT);
      if (strlen($2) > 0) {
          new->parms.next = $2;
      }
      $$ = new;
  }
```

-- *every* rule gets its own action; they are not 'shared' in any way between rules defined for the same non-terminal with `|`.  If you want to factor common code between the two actions, you should write it as a function, and make each action just a call to your function.

Comment: Oh, THAT's interesting! The entire original source was written like this (there are numerous examples). Is this a change in Bison or was yacc like this as well?

Comment: No, yacc and bison are identical in this respect.  As rules may not have a lot in common, its tough to see how one action could reasonably apply to more than one in the general case.